# One prepared statement for MSSQL and Oracle for retrieving Dates?

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, datetime, prepared-statement

I want to collect data from both MsSql and Oracle databases. Therefore I use an prepared statement because I need data `BETWEEN` a start and enddate.

**Given databases:**

So in `MSSQL` I have these columns:

- Startdate --> Datatype: `DATETIME`
- Enddate --> Datatype: `DATETIME`
- Name --> Datatype: `VARCHAR(100)`

In `Oracle` I have the same columns but other datatypes:

- Startdate --> Datatype: `Date`
- Enddate --> Datatype: `Date`
- Name --> Datatype: `VARCHAR2(100)`

Now I want to collect the data with the following Prepared SQL Statement:

```
String taskSql = "" +
" SELECT startdate, enddate, name" + 
" FROM TASKS" + 
" WHERE startdate BETWEEN ? AND ?" +
"  AND enddate BETWEEN ? AND ?";
```

This database date time stuff keeps confusing me and everytime I change my code it looks like it works, but when testing on other database it breaks.

**My Java code to collect data:**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(aEndDate);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
Date endDate = cal.getTime();

java.sql.Timestamp sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(startDate.getTime());
java.sql.Timestamp sqlEndDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(endDate.getTime());

System.out.println(sqlStartDate);  // prints 2012-02-23 00:00:00.0
System.out.println(sqlEndDate);    // prints 2012-02-23 23:59:59.0

PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

prepStatement = DB.getConnection().prepareStatement(taskSql);
prepStatement.setTimestamp(1, sqlStartDate);
prepStatement.setTimestamp(2, sqlEndDate);
prepStatement.setTimestamp(3, sqlStartDate);
prepStatement.setTimestamp(4, sqlEndDate);
resultSet = prepStatement.executeQuery();
```

Unfortunately I do not use JodaTime, next project I will, because I have read some good things about that library.

**My questions/problems are:**

- Can I used a prepared statement in Java for both MSSQL and Oracle databases?
- How can I use a generic date time format to collect the datetime from both databases? ( Or do I need to detect the database type and do some specific stuff?

Comment: Please show your `taskSql` as well.

Comment: Edited the post to show the correct Sql Statement

Comment: Try passing in java.sql.Dates instead of java.sql.Timestamps.

Comment: When I pass in java.sql.Dates it will not search on time, just Date and I want the time information too... therefore I use the BETWEEN.

Comment: That makes things more complicated. What error are you getting in the alternate database?

Comment: This is the error in Oracle when using TimeStamp OR Date: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: can you try (on oracle) this statement: "select dump(?) from dual" and give it `java.sql.Timestamp(startDate.getTime())` ? if you won't get the ORA-00923, it might help to see if it's typ=12 (date) or typ=180 (timestamp). And what oracle cersion are you usind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, own mistake that I was overseeing! I added an alias for my startdate and named this alias as `'from'` . Obviously this cannot work!